# Upgrading dpkg on 64-bit debian

Tags: linux, debian, 64bit, dpkg

Recently I tried to install Steam on my debian, but I ran into a problem. It requires `dpkg` version `1.16.2` (for multiarch) but the one installed on the system is `1.15.8.13`

The problem is that running `apt-get install dpkg` tells me that `dpkg` is the newest version. My searches yielded absolutely nothing about this issue

My machine:

```
Linux xel 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 15 15:39:52 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My sources.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 _Squeeze_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20120930-15:53]/ squeeze main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 _Squeeze_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20120930-15:53]/ squeeze main

#deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main non-free contrib
#deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main non-free contrib

#deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates contrib non-free
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates contrib non-free #Added by software-properties
#deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free

## squeeze-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
#deb http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free
#deb http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free #Added by software-properties
#deb-src http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: What Debian version are you running?

Comment: How exactly can I find that out? I already included uname -a

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. Means you're running stable. My suggestion would be to go with a combination of stable and testing, although many will blame me for this advice. Please post the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list first.

Comment: Wheezy is supposed to be released real soon now. As in, a few days from now. Upgrading to that will get you a new enough dpkg.

Comment: i edited the sources few minutes ago while trying to solve the issue (though i probably didn't really change anything as I commented the previous ones out). Only stable sources though

Answer (score 0):

Debian Wheezy includes a new enough version of dpkg, and is likely what the Steam developers are targeting. It is scheduled to be released this weekend.

It is currently the 'testing' release, but you can follow the [Wheezy release notes](http://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/releasenotes) and upgrade to it now, if you'd like. (Or follow them a few days from now, when it's released).

Chapter 4 of the release notes include detailed instructions for the upgrade (and will be quite familiar if you've upgraded between Debian versions before).